# ICS, WSocketServer and synchronization

Tags: delphi, synchronization, internet-component-suite

Could somebody tell me: if I use WsocketServer and procedure showed below:

```
  procedure TClientConnection.ConnectionDataAvailable(Sender: TObject;  Error: Word);
   var
   begin
   //code here
   end;
```

where TClientConnection class is descending from the TWSocketClient class,
have I use special type of synchronization when I want to:

1. build connection to database and modify data,
2. use and modyfy vcl components like for similar contents
   of Tmemo,
3. use global variables such as global arrays etc.

to avoid crach application, deadlock etc. when 10-20 clients are in the same time in connections and they are sending commands for manipulate data via ConnectionDataAvailable event?

Thank You very much for answers

Artik

Comment: It seems your `TClientConnection` is actually derived from `THttpConnection` which introduces `ConnectionDataAvailable`. I suppose you already have thread objects bound to each instance of the client, otherwise any type of synchronization is useless. In the multitheaded case you should use `Synchronize` for accessing GUI-related stuff (p.2 in your question), and a [critical section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686908(v=vs.85).aspx) for DB access and global arrays (pp. 1 and 3).

Comment: Thank You.My idea is to receive data from clients in certain time and store it in one table X. After this time or due to incoming date messages from clients, main thread (or pecial for this purpose thread) has to send statistics calculated on data from X, to all clients. This solution uses global arrays too,therefore I asked about it also. Obviously this process is repeated and data in table is increasing in time (it isn't clearing after statistic calculation) and it can be happend, statistics/sending work meat with incominng data events-therefore I so afraid about conflicts.

Comment: I think your concept is wrong in the part where you suppose that "main thread (or special for this purpose thread) has to send statistics calculated on data from X, to all clients". In the server you have a client object with a dedicated thread for every connected remote client. Every of these threads should be used both for receiving and sending data, that is a single connection is used per client. Inside each client thread all data flow is even-driven and does not require synchronization. It's necessary for accessing shared resources only - the DB table and global arrays.

Comment: When I've thought about it - You have absolutly right. Thank You. But maybe I have basic, fundamental Delphis question - how to simply and safety give this thread value (string or other non atomic value) from main thread  to send it to their client? If I understood well it is the way to broadcast the same data to all clients - give this data to their threads on server? I analize  sample exaple (OverbyteIcsThrdSrvV2 ) from elemantary packet of ICS instalation and although it looks nice and simple - I've problems - could You show me  a "fraction" of way for it?

Comment: There exist different options. For example, you may use `PostThreadMessage` to provide all threads with a pointer to data for broadcasting or just notify threads to look for the data at a global storage. As far as you only need to read this data from threads there is no need for a critical section - you may protect from reading non-consistent state by `Event` object, and check it in threads by `WaitForSingleObject(handle, 0)`. If you have problems with ICS examples, please post concrete questions (with code, errors, etc).

Comment: Thank You very much. If I'll loss my "game" with modification sample ICS for my purposes I'll send concrete question in separate "Ask". Regards!